# How to Highlight Unfilled Form Fields with JScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am doing a fill-up form page for my client and he wants it so that the unfilled text fields and selection parts to be highlighted when unfilled. Is there any way to do this with JavaScript/JQuery? Or do I have to do it with PHP?

I am really new at both. Any answer is very much appreciated. Thanks! :)

This is the page I'm trying to work on: http://firstnationsfinancing.com/cdapp.html

Comment: use jquery validate plugin

Comment: Trying this one as well.

Comment: @TamilSelvan, have used this method. You should've posted it as an answer so I can put check on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) ? It is very easy to use, and can highlight invalid form fields.

In basic implementation all you have to do is `<form data-parsley-validate>`. And yes dont forget to add [parsley's css](http://parsleyjs.org/src/parsley.css) as well.

Comment: No but will do now. Thank you so much for your answer. :)